# .Net Core Hosting in IIS , Error reading the web.config file HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web-config, iis-8

I am trying to host an asp.net core application in IIS 8.5  (windows server 2012) and there is something wrong with my web.config file. Here is a snapshot of of my config file.
[image]

I have installed .net core sdk 2.1.5 on the machine. below is the screen shot for installed .net core sdk and runtimes

[image]

I have deployed the same solution on another machine which is IIS 7.0 (windows 7) and its working fine there. but on this machine its not working.

In IIS inside fetures view i can't even open up any feature , like when i click on Default Document it prompts me the following error

[image]

If I delete my web.config file from source then i can open up any feature and that error goes away , but then on browsing the IIS complains for a default document not configured whereas i have configured the default documents.

As far as i suspect the issue is related with **aspNetCore** tag in web.config file which is not being recognized by IIS. but I am unable to fix this issue. I have tried installing other versions of .Net core sdk as well like dotnetsdk 2.1.202 or 2.1.4 but with no luck.

kindly help.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4

Comment: Thanx Lex Li , its a nice article .. i couldn't find it myself while after hours of searching ..

Comment: @umer You can also refer to this post http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/How-to-Publish-ASPNET-Core-2.aspx and http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/fix-502-error-asp-net-core.aspx. I also read this guidelines to publish my .net core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install .net core runtime 2.2 in ur system that should work and also when you publish the site put the configuration as framework dependent.. should solve the issue

Comment: Earlier i was trying to host .Net core app by installing .net core sdk on the machine,expecting it to install everything needed to run an ASP.Net core app. The sdk Installs the following runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
Microsoft.NETCore.App
Earlier i installed the same sdk on a machine and nothing else was needed to run  the app on that machine.
After reading @Lex Li article i uninstall the sdk and installed .NET Core Hosting Bundle instead. The hosting bundle installed the same modules mentioned above + MS .Net Core Runtimes, And everything work fine now.

Comment: I couldn't understand the scenario though , why on the first machine i do not had to install the MS .Net core runtimes and only the sdk installation was sufficient. while on the second machine i must have to install the .net core runtimes as well. 
The only difference i can see in both machines is that on first machine there's .Net framework 4.7 is installed while on the second machine .Net 4.5.1 is installed , is that the reason or i am missing something else?

Comment: i have used this link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2  and it works fine after installing .net core 2.2.